# Set a-tag to display: block but initially hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an anchor-tag (a-tag) that should be displayed as a block-element. That's because I want to specify the width, height and the padding of the element.

But initially this block-element has to be hidden so I set the display-value to none (display: none) in CSS.

So what happens? The a-tag is hidden but simultaneously an inline-element (a-tags are inline-elements by default).

Is there any chance to have an a-tag behave as a block-element but hidden in the initial state?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `The a-tag is hidden but simultaneously an inline-element (a-tags are inline-elements by default).`. Actually no, it would be `none`. `display: none` literally renders as though that element does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

`visibility: hidden` will hide the link but preserve the space it occupies. If this isn't ideal, use `font-size: 0` as well:

```
.hidden {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

An alternative is to use text-indent:

```
.hidden {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -999em;
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `font-size: 0`?

Comment: Well, he wants to hide the link without using display: none. The next best way to do that is to use visibility:hidden. However, that leaves a blank space where the link was. To completely remove all trace of the link, we give it a zero fontsize so that the links/text after it can take up that space.

Comment: `Is there any chance to have an a-tag behave as a block-element but hidden in the initial state?` I think he wants it to take up space? I don't know, it's a little fuzzy I guess

Comment: Yeah. He has both options in my answer, and can simply remove the font-size if that's his preference :)

Answer (score 1):

```
a{
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `visibility: hidden;` the object can be invisible and have dimensions (`diplay:block`).